# _RenderInkFeatures object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and don't know which problem is. As I reviewed error is that the `<Widget>` in `Widget build` working like a loop, while invoking methods, and creating infinite methods.

**LoginPage.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'main_page.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration (
        gradient: LinearGradient (
          colors: [
            Colors.blue,
            Colors.teal
          ],
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter
        )
      ),
      child: _isLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : ListView (
        children: <Widget>[
          headerSection(),
          textSection(),
          buttonSection(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  signIn(String email, String password) async {
    Map data = {
      'email': email,
      'password': password
    };

    var jsonData = null;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var response = await http.post("", body: data);

    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      _isLoading = false;
      jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      setState(() {
        sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonData['token']);
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainPage()), (Route<dynamic> route)  => false);
      });
    } else {
      print(response.body);
    }
  }

  Container buttonSection() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 40.0 ,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = true;
            });
            signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
          },
          color: Colors.purple,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          child: Text("Sign In", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70))
      ),
    );
  }

  final TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  Container textSection() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
      child: new Scaffold(
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: emailController,
              cursorColor: Colors.white,

              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.white70),
                hintText: "Email",
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70)),
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            TextFormField(
              controller: passwordController,
              cursorColor: Colors.white,

              obscureText: true,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.lock, color: Colors.white70),
                hintText: "Password",
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70)),
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Container headerSection() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 30.0),
      child: Text("Bob lox", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),

    );
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: RenderIndexedSemantics#7c292 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: index=1; layoutOffset=None (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=320.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  semantic boundary
...  size: MISSING
...  index: 1
The constraints that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were: BoxConstraints(w=290.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
The exact size it was given was: Size(290.0, Infinity)

See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:92:18
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2060:9)
#1      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2128:6)
#2      RenderBox.size=.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1846:7)
#3      RenderBox.size= (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1848:6)
#4      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:401:5)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#b7fbf relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=290.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(290.0, Infinity)
RenderObject: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#b7fbf relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=290.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(290.0, Infinity)
...  child 1: RenderFlex#a75fd NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    direction: vertical
...    mainAxisAlignment: start
...    mainAxisSize: max
...    crossAxisAlignment: center
...    verticalDirection: down
...    child 1: RenderMouseRegion#dcc07 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      listeners: enter, exit
...      cursor: SystemMouseCursor(text)
...      child: RenderIgnorePointer#7c564 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        ignoring: false
...        ignoringSemantics: implicitly false
...        child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#b3580 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          parentData: <none>
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...    child 2: RenderConstrainedBox#5d9df NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=30.0)
...    child 3: RenderMouseRegion#e2532 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      listeners: enter, exit
...      cursor: SystemMouseCursor(text)
...      child: RenderIgnorePointer#a517c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        ignoring: false
...        ignoringSemantics: implicitly false
...        child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#bb152 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          parentData: <none>
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...  child 2: RenderStack#dc014 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    alignment: centerRight
...    textDirection: ltr
...    fit: loose
...    child 1: RenderTransform#36528 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      transform matrix: [0] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[1] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
...      origin: null
...      alignment: center
...      textDirection: ltr
...      transformHitTests: true
...      child: RenderTransform#2661a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        transform matrix: [0] 0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[1] -0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
...        origin: null
...        alignment: center
...        textDirection: ltr
...        transformHitTests: true
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
_RenderInkFeatures object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:92:18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:92:18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderPadding object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Container file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:90:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderRepaintBoundary object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:31:72
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderIndexedSemantics object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:31:72
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: RenderIndexedSemantics#7c292 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: index=1; layoutOffset=116.0 (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=320.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  semantic boundary
...  size: Size(320.0, Infinity)
...  index: 1
The constraints that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were: BoxConstraints(w=290.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
The exact size it was given was: Size(290.0, Infinity)

See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:92:18
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2060:9)
#1      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2128:6)
#2      RenderBox.size=.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1846:7)
#3      RenderBox.size= (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1848:6)
#4      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:401:5)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#b7fbf relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=290.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(290.0, Infinity)
RenderObject: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#b7fbf relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=290.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(290.0, Infinity)
...  child 1: RenderFlex#a75fd NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    direction: vertical
...    mainAxisAlignment: start
...    mainAxisSize: max
...    crossAxisAlignment: center
...    verticalDirection: down
...    child 1: RenderMouseRegion#dcc07 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      listeners: enter, exit
...      cursor: SystemMouseCursor(text)
...      child: RenderIgnorePointer#7c564 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        ignoring: false
...        ignoringSemantics: implicitly false
...        child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#b3580 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none>
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...    child 2: RenderConstrainedBox#5d9df NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=30.0)
...    child 3: RenderMouseRegion#e2532 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      listeners: enter, exit
...      cursor: SystemMouseCursor(text)
...      child: RenderIgnorePointer#a517c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        ignoring: false
...        ignoringSemantics: implicitly false
...        child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#bb152 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none>
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...  child 2: RenderStack#dc014 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    alignment: centerRight
...    textDirection: ltr
...    fit: loose
...    child 1: RenderTransform#36528 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      transform matrix: [0] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[1] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
...      origin: null
...      alignment: center
...      textDirection: ltr
...      transformHitTests: true
...      child: RenderTransform#2661a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        transform matrix: [0] 0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[1] -0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
...        origin: null
...        alignment: center
...        textDirection: ltr
...        transformHitTests: true
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
_RenderInkFeatures object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:92:18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:92:18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderPadding object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Container file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:90:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderRepaintBoundary object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:31:72
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderIndexedSemantics object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:31:72
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: RenderIndexedSemantics#7c292 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: index=1; layoutOffset=116.0 (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=320.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  semantic boundary
...  size: Size(320.0, Infinity)
...  index: 1
The constraints that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were: BoxConstraints(w=290.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
The exact size it was given was: Size(290.0, Infinity)

See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:92:18
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2060:9)
#1      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2128:6)
#2      RenderBox.size=.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1846:7)
#3      RenderBox.size= (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1848:6)
#4      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:401:5)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#b7fbf relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=290.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(290.0, Infinity)
RenderObject: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#b7fbf relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=290.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(290.0, Infinity)
...  child 1: RenderFlex#a75fd NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    direction: vertical
...    mainAxisAlignment: start
...    mainAxisSize: max
...    crossAxisAlignment: center
...    verticalDirection: down
...    child 1: RenderMouseRegion#dcc07 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      listeners: enter, exit
...      cursor: SystemMouseCursor(text)
...      child: RenderIgnorePointer#7c564 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        ignoring: false
...        ignoringSemantics: implicitly false
...        child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#b3580 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none>
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...    child 2: RenderConstrainedBox#5d9df NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=30.0)
...    child 3: RenderMouseRegion#e2532 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      listeners: enter, exit
...      cursor: SystemMouseCursor(text)
...      child: RenderIgnorePointer#a517c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        ignoring: false
...        ignoringSemantics: implicitly false
...        child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#bb152 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none>
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...  child 2: RenderStack#dc014 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    alignment: centerRight
...    textDirection: ltr
...    fit: loose
...    child 1: RenderTransform#36528 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      transform matrix: [0] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[1] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
...      origin: null
...      alignment: center
...      textDirection: ltr
...      transformHitTests: true
...      child: RenderTransform#2661a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        transform matrix: [0] 0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[1] -0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
...        origin: null
...        alignment: center
...        textDirection: ltr
...        transformHitTests: true
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
_RenderInkFeatures object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:92:18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:92:18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderPadding object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Container file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:90:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderRepaintBoundary object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:31:72
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderIndexedSemantics object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///home/damir/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/login_page.dart:31:72
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add shrinkWrap: true in your ListView. The error explains when the scaffold is being drawn, the height is infinite. As Scaffold need some maximum height in order to work properly. You have used Scaffold Widget in a ListView that has infinite height. Either remove the scaffold widget or add height to its parent container. Also shrinkWrap your list.

Try This:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'main_page.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.teal],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter)),
      child: _isLoading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                headerSection(),
                textSection(),
                buttonSection(),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }

  signIn(String email, String password) async {
    Map data = {'email': email, 'password': password};

    var jsonData = null;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var response = await http.post("", body: data);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      _isLoading = false;
      jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      setState(() {
        sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonData['token']);
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainPage()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      });
    } else {
      print(response.body);
    }
  }

  Container buttonSection() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 40.0,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = true;
            });
            signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
          },
          color: Colors.purple,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          child: Text("Sign In", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70))),
    );
  }

  final TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  Container textSection() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
      child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          controller: emailController,
          cursorColor: Colors.white,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            icon: Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.white70),
            hintText: "Email",
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70)),
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 30.0),
        TextFormField(
          controller: passwordController,
          cursorColor: Colors.white,
          obscureText: true,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            icon: Icon(Icons.lock, color: Colors.white70),
            hintText: "Password",
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70)),
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }

  Container headerSection() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 30.0),
      child: Text("Bob lox", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    );
  }
}
```